# 3D Carousel Error In XML

Tags: android

I downloaded sample android carousel demo source code in the below link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel#xx4884593xx

The main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/carousel.main"
    xmlns:bm="carousel.main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#1E1921"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#A85E4F"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <carousel.Carousel
            android:id="@+id/carousel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:animationDuration="200"
            pj:Items="@array/entries"
            pj:SelectedItem="0"
            pj:UseReflection="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

However I'm now getting the following errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'UseReflection' in package 'carousel.main'    main.xml    
Suspicious namespace: should start with http:// main.xml
```

Each time I try and clean the project it deletes the R.file. I've tried changing the package name, and pasting all the contents again but that hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. 
In the root of the xml:

```
xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/package_with_calling_class"
    xmlns:bm="package_with_calling_class"
```

package_with_calling_class = the class which might be the main activity where the onCreate() is being called. In my case it was platinum.platinumstars
setContent(R.layout.main)